# Can spark deal with views the same way it deals with persisted tables?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, view, apache-spark-sql

I have a view created using hive which is nothing but a simple union of two tables. I want to read the view in spark and do operations on it.

Will spark treat the view differently when it reads the table. As in, is the view read using map-reduce (that hive would use) or is it read by spark by parallelizing the partitions (the way it usually reads tables).

I preferred the view approach rather than creating another table with the union because of the useless duplication of data and the space that would get wasted due to it.

Comment: Thoughts... 1) Try changing hive execution engine to Spark or Tez, 2) Create the [temp or global] view in spark. Not sure if hive views would be available in spark (I'd theorize yes), but the execution I suspect would still be in hive to materialize to spark.

Comment: @Garren Thanks for your thoughts. I'll try it out and check if the execution is being done in hive or spark to be sure.